# Open a URL with the OS default action from Python

Tags: python, windows, steam

I'm editing a program called TF2idle that can be seen here:
http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1161862

I'm adding a button to defrag any of the accounts that are selected using the person's source he has available.

I found in the python files that this is where all the magic happens and is what I need to edit to add my Defrag button.

http://pastebin.com/9PjzqU5u

Lines 136 - 142 and 328-337 I added myself. These lines are below:

```
startDefragIcon = QtGui.QIcon()
            startDefragIcon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(returnResourcePath('images/defrag.png')), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.startDefragAction = self.mainwindow.htoolBar.addAction(startDefragIcon, 'Defrag Accounts')
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.startDefragAction, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), curry(self.startUpAccounts, action='start_Defrag'))
```

and

```
 if action == 'start_Defrag':
                                    command = r'"%s/Steam.exe" -login %s %s' % (sandbox_install, username, password)
                                    if easy_sandbox_mode == 'yes' and self.settings.get_option('Account-' + account, 'sandbox_install') == '':
                                            self.commandthread.addSandbox('TF2Idle' + username)
                                            self.createdSandboxes.append(username)
                                            command = r'"%s/Start.exe" /box:%s %s' % (sandboxielocation, 'TF2Idle' + username, command)
                                    else:
                                            command = r'"%s/Start.exe" /box:%s %s' % (sandboxielocation, sandboxname, command)
                                    #Right here add script to launch steam://defrag/440
```

A way the program can defrag the accounts is to launch "steam://defrag/440" and that will automatically do it. For an example, I can put in my google chrome address bar that address and it will tell steam to defrag the program with the ID 440, which is TF2.

Thing is, I have no idea how to add that to the script. I was thinking of adding a BAT file which would have "steam://defrag/440" inside it and add a line that would launch said BAT file at line 336.

I'm hoping someone here knows how I can accomplish this.

Second problem is that I have no idea how to turn all these source files after I finished editing into an .EXE. I know this is all advanced for me, but I gotta start learning if I want to go to college for computer science, plus this would really help out many users using this tool.

Comment: You need to post the *relevant* code here, not link to it somewhere else. Expecting people to leave this site, read your code, and then return here to answer is unreasonable, and not having the code here means your question is meaningless if the external site is unavailable for some reason. It also means it's not searchable for future readers. Please edit and include *the part that is relevant to the problem you're having* here. Thanks.

Comment: Building the exe: [_described in the code_](https://github.com/Moussekateer/TF2IdleGUI/blob/master/TF2Idle.spec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want the [webbrowser module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('steam://defrag/440')
```

Comment: Didn't think it was that simple. I ran it through IDLE and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is a request to that address, python supplies simple modules to handle it.

```
from httplib2 import Http
h = Http
h.request('steam://defrag/440', 'GET')
```

Comment: Seems to me that's unlikely to work, as you need to use the platform-configured handler for the "steam:" protocol scheme. Unless Python is substantially more magic than I believe, httplib2 won't know about that scheme.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't. I'm looking for another solution, otherwise I'll remove the answer.

Comment: I'm not running Windows; if you're set up to test this, perhaps you can see whether the answer I posted works?

Comment: It returns `True`, although no new window opens in my default browser.

Answer (score 1):

This may not qualify as an answer per se, but since your question doesn't really qualify as a question either (:-P),  here are some tips:

- The Steam client registers itself as a URL handler for the `steam://` protocol.
- You should be able to achieve the workflow you proposed using the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module.
- Anything you can do in a BAT file, you can do in a Python script.
- In general, Python scripts are not compiled (e.g. to .exe files). That said, there *is* [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) which wraps the interpreter, code, and dependencies into a .exe file package.

EDIT: See Eric's comment on your question regarding the last bit.